# Error in installing webpack on REACT: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that

Tags: reactjs, webpack, cmd, webpack-dev-server

Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.

- > configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:
  > object { defaultRules?, exprContextCritical?, exprContextRecursive?, exprContextRegExp?, exprContextRequest?, noParse?, rules?, strictExportPresence?, strictThisContextOnImports?, unknownContextCritical?, unknownContextRecursive?, unknownContextRegExp?, unknownContextRequest?, unsafeCache?, wrappedContextCritical?, wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextRegExp? }
  > -> Options affecting the normal modules (`NormalModuleFactory`).
- > configuration.output.path: The provided value "dist/assets" is not an absolute path!
  > -> The output directory as **absolute path** (required).

---

In React Tutorial course("Building with webpack")
(I use of windows but course is on linux)

[my webpack.config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4b0Az.jpg)

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: "dist/assets",
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "assets"
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: './dist',
        port: 3000
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: ["babel-loader"],
                query: {
                    presets: ["latest", "react", "stage-0"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

[project directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArMF6.jpg)

[my index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kF6W.jpg)

```
const { createElement } = React
const { render } = ReactDOM

const style = {
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
    color:'white',
    fontFamily: 'verdana'
}

const title = createElement(
    'h1',
    {id:'title', className:'header', style: style},
    'hello world'
)

render(
    <h1 id='title'
        className='header'
        style={{backgroundColor:'orange'}}>
    hello world
    </h1>,
    document.getElementById('react-container')
)
```

[my cmd with command "webpack" to convert index.js to bundle.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpZld.jpg)

[tutorial's terminal that run webpack successfully!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBgLv.jpg)

Comment: This is a coding site, we expect to see the code, not just error messages it outputs. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64035051/edit), to provide it, _(properly formatted)_.

Comment: @Compo Ok Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

1. You are using an invalid key, `loaders`. It should be `rules`.
   This was changed from Webpack v2 onwards. See this page for more information:
   https://webpack.js.org/migrate/3/#module-loaders-is-now-module-rules
2. `query` has been deprecated in favour of `options`:
   https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleoptions--rulequery
3. The value for the `loader` key should not be an array.

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      loader: "babel-loader",
      options: {
        presets: ["latest", "react", "stage-0"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million. Yesss, it fixed the error described above, but it made several other errors ;)

1-> The output directory as **absolute path (required)**
**Answer->** change output to (__dirname+"/dist/assets")

2-> Error: options/query cannot be used with loaders (use options for each array item) in {..
**Answer->** I removed the [] around ["babel-loader"] (loader: "babel-loader")

3-> **npm install --save-dev babel-loader@7**

4-> Finally **webpack --mode development** And Done!!

Should we put the code as the final answer? Or not needed. Thanks for your help, it was very useful

Comment: @Mostafaghafari I have updated my answer with more information :)